# How can select Top 100 rows from a table and update a column value as 'inprogress' for all those selected rows

Tags: sql

How can select Top 100 rows from a table and update a  column value as 'in progress'  for all those selected rows.Also i need to get all those items in a single select Query.

```
SELECT TOP 100 [column 1],[column 2],[column 3] 
FROM table name  
where column 3 = 'Null';

update top (100) table name 
     set column 3= 'in progress' 
where column 3= '';
```

...i am used this select query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your question is unclear.  Are you looking for an `update` query or a `select`?  If both, then the question is too broad.

Comment: "...Top 100 rows" -- You'll need to provide a criteria to decide what that means. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use update-able cte :

```
with u_cte as (
     select col3, row_number() over (order by ?) as seq
     from table t
     where col3 is null
)
update u_cte 
       set col3 = 'in progress'
where seq <= 100;
```

`?` use ordering column instead that specify column ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of sql you are using but you could put the items into a temporary table and update them that way

```
select top 100 * into #table1 from table2 where 1=1

UPDATE #table1 set x = x
```

The temporary table will stay valid until that sql window is closed.

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT TOP 100 [column1]
      ,[column2]
      ,[column3]
  FROM [temp].[dbo].[abc]  where column3= 'Null'; 

  update top (100) [temp].[dbo].[abc] set column3= 'inprogress' where column3= '';